# How to separate app audio files from whatsapp audio files in android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am creating a music player app and I am querying songs with the following code.

```
if(musicResolver != null){
    musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri,null,null,null,null);
}

if(musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int idCol = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
    int titleCol = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int artistCol = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
    do {
        long id       = musicCursor.getLong(idCol);
        String title  = musicCursor.getString(titleCol);
        String artist = musicCursor.getString(artistCol);
        MusicService.songsSet.add(new Song(id,title,artist));
    } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

The problem is along with songs I am getting WhatsApp audio files. Is there a way to filter them.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several ways by which you can filter out WhatsApp Audio Records. I am listing the most basic and easiest approach which you can use:

**1. Ignoring the Audio folder of WhatsApp (WhatsApp Audio)**: Get the real path from the URI and ignore all files having path (`WhatsApp/WhatsApp Audio/*`).

**2. Ignore Files with the names starting with `AUD-000000-WA0000.*`**: This is again a pattern matching (Regex) to ignore all files having name matching the above pattern. WhatsApp Audio files have a specific file name pattern. So you can easily ignore them too.

Both these methods should get you to filter out WhatsApp Audio files and leave you with other sound files only.

Comment: "title != 'AUD-.*-WA.*'" i am using this string in the selection argument but it is not affecting anything

Comment: String comparison doesn't work like that in Java. For string comparison, `.equals()` function is to be used. Also, you need to `regex` match the pattern to check if the filename is in the above pattern. The way you are trying to match is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You Can you below 2 lines, it is working for me, it is avoided to take Whatsapp Audio while querying to the content manager for the audio file.

```
where.append(" AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " NOT  LIKE  'AUD%'");
where.append(" AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " NOT  LIKE  'PTT%'");
```